# 'find' is not recognised as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to install Google cloud SDK in my PC.

I changed the current directory to `C:\google-cloud-sdk` where the install.bat file is located.

I'm unable to run the batch file from cmd and it gives the following error when I type install.bat in the cmd:

```
'find' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program, batch file.
```

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding `C:\WINDOWS\system32;` to the beginning of my `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds as though your `PATH` environment variable is not defined properly. It should contain a list of paths to standard and installed software. Perhaps your batch file is defining its own `PATH` value, which would break the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The batch file `install.bat` uses the command `find`, which doesn't seem to be on your PC (or at least, not in a directory in the `path` variable). Try open a command prompt and type the command `find`. If you receive the same error, try the command `findstr`. If `findstr` works replace the usage of `find` in `install.bat` with `findstr`. You may also need to change the syntax of the command, please post here if that occurs and you require help.

Comment: Hello, unclemeat thanks for the reply. I tried typing findstr, its also  giving the same error. Please Help.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: much more important: what does `echo %path%` say?