# LogCat android unity3d game crashing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, logcat

Building an android game in UNITY, with `admob` and external links in `playmaker` using `applicationOpenURL` `FSM`. Since I've been building with the `admob` and external links, my game isn't building properly, but I`m not getting any error codes in unity.

retracing every single step I've made:

```
C:\Users\tstw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>10-08 15:33:32.454  
3285  3285 D MotionRecognitionService: disableGripSensor : Enabled true  
slot 0 (true)
'10-08' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\tstw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>10-08 15:33:32.459  
3285  3285 D `MotionRecognitionService`: clear `SAR_DEVICE_GRIP`
'10-08' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z8hbNZKfmSbudyGyDyJGk68NPRymwZLk

please use the google drive to view the command prompt `logcat` outputs...

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment yet but this link might help you through out your debugging process

1. [is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file 1st link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)
2. [is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file 2nd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485497/find-is-not-recognised-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-ba)

This is not an answer actually but I can't yet have a comment .